# java.io.EOFexception when running my application on real device

Tags: android, exception, mobile-application

i am developing an application that request data from MYSQL
i used an API (json) to retrieve the data from database.

My problem is that **my project works fine on android studio** **but when i am running it on real device (Samsung GT-I9082) i got an exception and i don't know why!**

the exception is:

```
java.io.EOFexception
```

mycode:

```
  private void getData(String leng) {

       final String  id="23119574";

            try {
                if (id.equals("")) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter an id", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    return;
                }
                loading = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Please wait...", "Fetching...", false, false);

                //  String url = config.DATA_URL3+id;
                String url = config.DATA_URL4 + id;


                StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        loading.dismiss();
                        showJSON(response, id);
                    }
                },
                        new Response.ErrorListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                                Toast.makeText(Handler_Barcode.this, error.getMessage().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        });

                RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
                stringRequest.setRetryPolicy((new DefaultRetryPolicy(
                        20000,
                        0,
                        DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT)));
                requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


    }
```

note: i am using volley

and my device android version is 4.2.2

thank you!

Comment: Please post your stackTrace or anything about the error, number of line.

Comment: @GeniusQ the error occurs only when i am running the app on real device, it is working fine on android studio emulator.